# Select only specific fields in Magento

Tags: magento, collections

I'm trying to use the MAX function of MySQL to retrieve the latest dates from my table.

```
$_updates = Mage::getModel('ticket/updates')->getCollection();  
$_updates->getSelect()->columns('MAX(created) as max_created')->group(array('status_id'));
```

This is the resulting query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, MAX(created) AS `max_created` FROM `em_ticket_updates` AS `main_table` GROUP BY `status_id`
```

The problem with this is that if all the fields are included (`main_table.*`)  it does not function correctly.

Is there a way to remove `main_table.*` from the query and only use specific fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A Zend trick can be used here.

```
$_updates->getSelect()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns('MAX(created) as max_created')
    ->group(array('status_id'));
```

**NOTE:**

For EAV collection you must re-add the `entity_id` or you will have an error when the collection is loaded.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(array('entity_id')); 

    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('image','small_image','thumbnail'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $simple_ids));
```

Comment: Thank you! Saw the reset method on the Magento documentation but not the parameter value. Guess I should really study Zend too.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for since long. Absolutely awesome answer! Thanks for saving my day!

Comment: Saved me from searching for too long, i ran into this issue when trying to set the columns in the "from" while adding "join" later and was scratching my head why it's including other columns from the joined tables. This reset trick solved it!

Answer (score 7):

Magento provide addFieldToSelect() fumctionality. Use below code to get specific field.

```
$Collection = Mage::getModel('showdown/votes')->getCollection();
$Collection->addFieldToSelect('id');
```

Comment: you can select more than one field with array, e.g. `$Collection->addFieldToSelect(array('field_1', 'field_2');`

Comment: Thanks for this nice and easy solution ! Works great in Magento 2.1 !

Answer (score 5):

I recognise this is an old post but I thought I'd post an alternative solution.

I had a similar problem myself, I eventually searched through the source until I reached `Zend_Db_Select` After consulting the [Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns) (Example 8).

```
$select = $db->select()
    ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
           array('product_id', 'product_name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use "**getColumnValues**"

```
$_updates = Mage::getModel('ticket/updates')->getCollection(); 
$columnValues = $_updates->getColumnValues('Your Column Name');
```